# Oracle error when executing stored procedure: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: java, angularjs, oracle

This is the complete error :

> Code : -6502
>   Message : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too smallORA-06512: at "MYDATABASE"

This is how I execute the procedure in my java service :

```
public String[] execpross_p_hra_int_population_trim () throws SQLException, Exception {
    Connect("DBALIAS");

    String SQL = "{call EDD_CONFID.P_HRA_INT_POPULATION_TRIM (?, ?)}";
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall (SQL);

    String status[];
    status = new String[2];

    Integer P_CODEERREUR = 0;
    String P_TEXTEERREUR = null;

    try {

        cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

       cs.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("Erreur SQL : "+e);
    }
    finally {

       P_CODEERREUR = cs.getInt(1);
       P_TEXTEERREUR = cs.getString(2);

       cs.close();
    }

    status[0] = P_CODEERREUR.toString();
    status[1] = P_TEXTEERREUR;
    return status;
}
```

I'm using the correct JDBC drivers for my base, (12.1.0.2.0)

After a lot of research it would seems like a "locale" problem. Since my base it's set in French. I tried adding locals and even the internationalization java library Oracle provides. But nothing seems to work.

I can't really debug the stored procedure because I didn't do it, but when I execute it with SQL Developer all seems good.

Now I have some weird behavior, in my dev environment, whenever I start the service, I have the same error, but then, after some minutes it just start working without errors. How is this even possible ?

So my conclusions so far, either I need to find a way to work with the NLS_LANG settings (witch I don't really understand how to use it in my case) or I have some incompatible data in my DB. But I couldn't identify it.

I know this is an specific problem, and I'm not looking for a direct solution, just if you guys can help me going in the right direction ? Since I'm pretty lost over here.

Comment: Looks like the error is inside the procedure, so you would need to look at the full stack trace (from `e`) to get the line number(s)  and also be able to see the procedure code; which *might* be visible to you in `all_source`; but could be wrapped or you might not have privileges. Your assumption is that there is a string variable that is too small for a multibyte value? The error you've shown is in English though, so why do you think it's a French issue, and how/where do you set the locale?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks a lot for the quick answer. I'm in contact with the procedure programmer and I can indeed see it in my SQLDevelopper IDE. When we execute it directly from there all seems to work fine. The problem only happends when my API (the method I added) tries to execute it. And that it's my assuption yes. I tryed setting the locales in my java code, but nothing seems to changes, that's why I'm not really sure that's the solution.

Comment: If you can see the procedure code and the line numbers from the stack trace, you can see where the error is actually coming from? Even if you can't post the procedure code here, that should narrow it down. (I would *guess* some real error is occurring and the proc is catching that and trying to copy the error code into a local variable and then into the out parameter; and the local variable is too small. But pure speculation..) Are you connected as the same DB user through Java and SQL Developer?

Comment: @AlexPoole I'll try to debug the procedure, but if I execute it in debug mode in SQLDevelopper all seems fine, I don't have any error message or problem. That's a pretty good idea, by the local variable you mean the one that it's instantiated in the java code ? If that's the case how can I set the chars on it ? I coudn't find any example in java, only in C.

Comment: No, within the procedure. But without seeing the code amd stack trace it's just (rather pointless) speculation. I don't believe how you are calling it from Java can be the issue, the size of a Java string is way too large. Are you doing everythign as the same DB user? If not is the procedure (or the package it's part of) defined as authid current_user?

Comment: Actually, assuming `EDD_CONFID` is a package not a schema, is there package instantiation code - i.e. code in a `begin` block after all the prodecure/function code? If there is and *that* is causing the error, it might explain what you're seeing in your dev env. First call in a session hits the error, subsequent calls don't, because instantiation only happens once per session? Still all guesswork though.

Comment: Actually EDD_CONFID it's an schema (sorry I should have told you).
We added code errors on the procedure and the procedure programmer told me when my API launchs it, it cant continue where some functions like  "13-length(to_char..." are used. So the error may come from here. But what justify the fact that this error only happends when executing the procedure with the JDBC driver (API) and not when doing it with SQLDevelopper ? Also thanks a lot for your time I really apreciate that 
EDIT : will it change something the fact that calling it  with a PL/SQL block ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137603/discussion-between-russo-and-alex-poole).